# How to send methods to Rabbitmq queue in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I'm trying to create queue inside HttpPost method so when I use it functions that is inside will go to queue and would execute after some time.

What I tried to do is:

```
[HttpPost(Name = "add-message")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostMessage([FromBody] MessengerViewModel messengerViewModel)
    {
        AtSmsSender smsSender = new AtSmsSender();
        InnerAtSmsReceiver innerAtSmsReceiver = new InnerAtSmsReceiver(_asynchMessagesService);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        var currentUserId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                durable: false,
                exclusive: false,
                autoDelete: false,
                arguments: null);

            await smsSender.SendSms(messengerViewModel.PhoneNr, messengerViewModel.MessageBody);
            await innerAtSmsReceiver.ReceiveSms();
            await _asynchMessagesService.SaveSentMessage(currentUserId, messengerViewModel.ContactId,
                messengerViewModel.MessageBody, now,
                true, messengerViewModel.State);

            channel.BasicPublish(
                exchange: "",
                routingKey: "hello",
                basicProperties: null);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

I don't know is it proper way to use RabbitMQ queue. I want to get some tips for rabbitmq or maybe another way to put those three **await** methods into queue as I'm now out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

That should publish a message to the `hello` queue. If you expect `PostMessage` to be executed frequently you would use long-running `connection` and `channel` objects and not create new ones each method call. There are several other changes you can make if this method is called frequently, like doing the SMS and RabbitMQ work on another thread.